# Checking Equality of two Lists throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android

In my Android app I want to check whether there are equal elements in two different lists. But there is always an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and I don't know what's wrong. So could you help me please.

Here's the function:

```
private void checkEquality(){
    if(!langlist.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= langlist.size(); i++) {
            if (!selectedlang.isEmpty()) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= selectedlang.size(); j++) {
                    if (langlist.get(i).getName().equals(selectedlang.get(j).getName())) {
                        System.out.println(i + " / " + langlist.size() + " removed");
                        langlist.remove(i);

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.vocabapp, PID: 6407
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vocabapp/com.example.vocabapp.LanguageList}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2977)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6831)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:927)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at com.example.vocabapp.LanguageList.checkEquality(LanguageList.java:143)
    at com.example.vocabapp.LanguageList.onCreate(LanguageList.java:72)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6831) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:927)
```

Comment: `i <= langlist.size()` must be `i < langlist.size()` same in the next line

Comment: Ok, thank yout, but it doesn't work either

Comment: *it doesn't work* is not an error description. Is there an other exception or an unexpected result?

Comment: same goes for j in inner loop.

Comment: You are just removing common elements from your two lists. How about this approach of Java 8? `langlist.removeIf(selectedlang::contains);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first list is updated after remove so you have to recall this checkEquality() function and add `return;` before this line `langlist.remove(i);`
so your if condition will be like

```
if(..equals..){
    langlist.remove(i);
    checkEquality()
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are index is from `0` till the size of the list, instead it should be `size - 1`.

Replace, `i <= langlist.size()` with `i < langlist.size()`, same with the inner loop variable `j` `j <= langlist.size()` with `j < langlist.size()`.

Even then your logic is wrong, you need to remove from the inner list instead of the outer list, i.e replace `langlist.remove(i);` with `selectedlang.remove(j);`.

Also the better way to do this is,

```
public static <T> boolean listEqualsIgnoreOrder(List<T> a, List<T> b) {
    return new HashSet<>(a).equals(new HashSet<>(b));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your for loop on list.size() you want < not <=

You might want to try an easier to read solution, though, like applying a predicate to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

when you call `remove()` method on `langlist` the size of the list is updated but you are still incrementing `i` which causes this problem
try iterating the loop in reverse order to prevent errors like this:

```
for (int i = langlist.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
// do checks and deletions here
}
```

you can also use `removeIf()` method to delete common items if you are using java8 as @malware stated